# Eclipse Palette unavailable

Tags: eclipse, macos

When using Eclipse on my Macbook Pro I am not able to use the Palette capability. A message appears that says "A palette is not available". if anyone could provide me with insight on this matter it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the page in Web page editor.

Right click on the page and select **Web page editor**.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but maybe I can help someone else.
the "A palette is not available" is only there because you haven't opened a Report/Page yet. to do so:
File -> New -> Project -> Report Project.
Then create a new page:
File -> New -> Report -> *Select The Project you've just created* -> Finish.

Good Luck